# Multiple After on Tkinter made the GUI frozen

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, tkinter

recently im working using Python with Tkinter gui. The problem is , i want to show some lines by changing its state from hidden to normal within some interval, let's say it 1s.

So , the line will show up 1 by 1 within 1 second. 
When i tried, the commandline works perfectly(i print some text on windows cmd) But, the gui frozen until the end of the computation then all of the lines showed up(not 1 by 1), idk why?  im new with python :(

here's my dummy code

```
def delay():
allline=mainframe.find_withtag('line')
for i in allline:
    tags=mainframe.gettags(i)
    print(tags[0])
    root.after(1000, mainframe.itemconfigure(tags[0],state='normal'))
......
mainframe.create_line((50,50,100,100),...,tags=('line1','line'),state='hidden')
mainframe.create_line((150,150,100,100),...,tags=('line2','line'),state='hidden')
```

let's say i have a button which trigger delay function.

Thanks for ur help! sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Rather than using a for loop like this, get all the lines into a list and call a function which removes the first line from the list, shows the line and then have the function call itself using after. Next time the function is called the next item is removed from the list, line made visible etc etc. This way tkinter has time to update the screen.

Comment: You're not using `after` properly.  You're immediately calling the function, and then giving the result to the `after` command.

Comment: @Akbar Noto You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a for loop like this, get all the lines into a list and call a function which removes the first line from the list, shows the line and then have the function call itself using after. Next time the function is called the next item is removed from the list, line made visible etc etc. This way tkinter has time to update the screen.

```
import tkinter as tk

lines = []

def showNextLine():
    global lines
    try:
        nextLine = lines.pop(0)
        canvas.itemconfigure(nextLine,state='normal')
        root.after(1000,showNextLine)
    except IndexError:
        pass
        #No more items in list.

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas()
canvas.grid()
canvas.create_line((50,50,100,100),fill='red',tags=('line1','line'),state='hidden')
canvas.create_line((50,60,100,110),fill='blue',tags=('line2','line'),state='hidden')
canvas.create_line((50,70,100,120),fill='yellow',tags=('line3','line'),state='hidden')
canvas.create_line((50,80,100,130),fill='green',tags=('line4','line'),state='hidden')

lines = list(canvas.find_withtag('line'))
print(type(lines),lines)
root.after(1000,showNextLine)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried ur code and its work perfectly, sorry for late reply. imma out of my town hehe...
ill try to insert it to my main project, thanks!